# Adverbs of manner such as “alphabetically” and “comically”

Tags: adverbs

“I arranged books alphabetically” means I arranged books in a way that has the same order as the letters of the alphabet.

(That is, the books became alphabetical.)

In the same way, can “I changed books comically” mean I changed books into comical books?

(That is, the books became comical.)

If you know Korean, you know you just need to add adverbs of manner to indicate the result by action of objects. Can “I changed books comically” mean I changed books into comical books?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @fev Can “I changed books comically” mean I changed books into comical books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't. The sentence is unusual, but one can imagine situations where one could say that. In any case, ***comically*** is an adverb that shows the manner in which you changed the books. So I would understand that yes ***the result was comic***, but *not as an attribute of the books themselves*: it is their new arrangement or sequence that is comic.

Comment: Hi, fev. Why is Korean so semantically strange? For example, I eat a delicious food, we call it 음식을 맛있게 먹다 which means I eat food deliciously in English. I’m asking because you like foreign languages.

Comment: I don't speak Korean, but from my experience with languages, each language has words, nuances, _structures and constructions_ specific only to them, and attempts to transpose them to other languages as such will sound foreign and clumsy in the target language. T's just the way it is!